# Created Invalid image

Tags: php, screenshot, snapshot

Tried to create image from url. But creating invalid image.

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

used cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

allow_url_fopen set to true:

Comment: Are your `header` to write correct?

Comment: All the functions you use provide ways to determine whether they ran successfully and, otherwise, obtain an error message with the appropriate information. That information can be found in the corresponding manual pages. You can only skip error checking if you're certain that it cannot fail, which is obviously not the case. Also, I suspect you might not even know if your PHP settings allow you to see error messages. Last but not least, the obvious thing to do with an image that "does not work" is to see its size (with your favourite file manager) and open it in a text editor if non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a problem in your configurations not allowing external URLs to be accessed. I can make both of your code variants work just fine.

Be sure that `allow_url_fopen` is really enabled. The following PHP code should help. It should be set to `1`.

```
echo 'allow_url_fopen has the following value: '.ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

Note that `allow_url_fopen` [cannot be enabled via `ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php); the entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf only.

---

Additional suggestions:

1. Output all errors during development. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your file.
2. Simply your code as much as possible, i.e. use a simple file name in `$dir` and add the subdirectories only later.

This yields the following code (added an actual working value in `$url` for testing purposes):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/morcha/browsers/256/Firefox-icon.png';
$img = 'flower.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

If this code does not work, please supply **all errors that have been output** as well as **the contents of the local image file** (if it has been created).